# I try to build a basic Odoo 15 module but gives error at inheritance

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to create a graphical reporting module but gives error at inheritance.
I start basic by inheritance the crm modules to manage them.
My modules is:

```
class XPFReporting(models.Model):
    """
    This is the reporting system that will take all data from crm to further filter and order it
    """
    _name = 'xpf.reporting'
    _description = "XPF Reporting"
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    custom_field = fields.Char(string='Custom Field')
```

and my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <!-- View for model -->
    <record id="view_xpf_reporting_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">xpf.reporting.tree</field>
        <field name="model">xpf.reporting</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="default tree">
                <field name="custom_field"/>
                <!-- <field name="*" /> -->
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!-- Define the button to generate PDF report -->
    <record id="view_xpf_reporting_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">xpf.reporting.form</field>
        <field name="model">xpf.reporting</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <field name="custom_field"/>
                <!--
                group - Place holder for filtering
                -->
                <footer>
                    <button string="Generate PDF Report" type="object" class="oe_highlight" icon="fa-file-pdf-o"
                            name="generate_pdf_report"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_xpf_reporting" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">XPF Reporting</field>
        <field name="res_model">xpf.reporting</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_xpf_reporting" name="XPF Reporting" action="action_xpf_reporting" parent="" sequence="1"/>

</odoo>
```

The issue is when I try to install it returns:
`TypeError: Many2many fields xpf.reporting.tag_ids and crm.lead.tag_ids use the same table and columns`

Any idea is gladly appreciated.
Merci

Comment: Try to redefine the `tag_ids` field and change the table name ( Change `crm_tag_rel` to `xpf_reporting_crm_tag_rel`)

Answer (score 0):

For standard model inheritance in Odoo (and DB tables) you **must not** define a `_name`.

```
class XPFReporting(models.Model):
    """
    This is the reporting system that will take all data from crm to further filter and order it
    """
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    custom_field = fields.Char(string='Custom Field')
```